# sql SELECT IF AND ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a query like this:

```
   SELECT priority, likes FROM table ORDER BY priority, likes DESC;
```

The priority and likes are integer polls. I would like to add 'IF' clause that

```
  IF (priority > 1 AND priority < 100)
  {
      ORDER BY priority;
  }
  ELSE
  {
      ORDER BY likes DESC;
  }
```

I don't know how to ask about it. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the sense? How can be "conditional order"? The could be only consecutive order. I.e. what records come first: with `1<priority<100` or something else?

Comment: Please provide few rows of sample data and a desired result to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN priority > 1 AND priority < 100 THEN priority ELSE likes END DESC
```

Comment: But OP wants to order by `priority ASC` instead of `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean?

```
SELECT priority, likes 
FROM table 
WHERE priority > 1 AND priority < 100  
ORDER BY priority, likes DESC;
```

ah just looked at your update, try this

```
SELECT priority, likes 
FROM table 
ORDER BY IF(priority > 1 AND priority < 100, priority, likes DESC)
```

or a case like i would use

```
SELECT priority, likes 
FROM table
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN priority > 1 AND priority < 100 
         THEN priority 
         ELSE likes 
END ASC
```

Note: syntax might be a tad off, not got my sql open on this slow pc

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?

```
SELECT priority, likes
FROM table
ORDER BY IF (priority > 1 AND priority < 100, priority, 0 - likes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT priority, likes FROM table 
ORDER BY IF(priority > 1 AND priority < 100, priority, likes DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort differently based on a condition.  The field "priority" is per record and thus it doesn't make sense to ORDER BY based on a fields value.

Perhaps have a SQL condition and then 1 SELECT with the appropriate ordering, else do a different SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

ok you are right, it can not be sort differently based on a condition. I solve this problem by making a parameter likes/priority as prio and order by DESC